# Store model with relations in one method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, relation

It is possible in Laravel to store JSON for a new model with relation models (existing or new) in one `save()`/`create()` method?

For example:

```
{
    "name": "Name of new Model A record",
    ...
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 123, # ID of existing record of Model B
        },
        {
            "name": "Create new Model B record"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code for writing:

```php
ModelA::create([
  "name" => "Name of...",
  "comments" => [
    ["id" => 123],
    ["name" => "Create new..."],
  ],
]);
```

Method `ModelA::create()`/`ModelA::save()` write to database just record of Model A. Record of ModelB not created.

Any errors.

Relations in models are correct.

**P.S.** I using UUID as primary and foreign keys.

Comment: What do you mean "_store JSON for a new model_", what does store JSON mean in code? Aren't you using `Model::create(...)` or similar?

Comment: Yes, I use `Model::create()`.

Comment: And what are you doing? share code, I honestly do not understand what you mean, are you getting an error? how are you trying to store this info?

Comment: Which DB system do you use? MongoDB?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Updated.

Comment: @flappix MySQL.

Comment: I honestly never tried trying to store a multi array, but I am assuming you cannot do what you want to do, you cannot store multiple information in a single query like that one, specially because you are using a Model, and that has its own query, and you are trying to shove another's model data onto it. You could if you are using a RAW SQL query using `DB` facade, but I would not recommend this unless you have a lot of info and you truly need a single query. Why are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Of course I cannot do this in one query in SQL. I mean, I would like use one method built-in Laravel. I moving code from CakePHP to Laravel and it was possible in Cake (https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations).

Comment: @kicaj oh, I see, it makes sense there. We do not have that on laravel (natively), what you can do is create the parent model and then create the child directly from a relationship, for example `ModelA::create(X)->comments()->create(Y);` that would create a ModelA with the expected `ModelA`'s `X` data, and then, using the relationship `comments`, you create comments using `Y` data, and also associate it to the `ModelA` you just created

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks, but I knew this solutions. I think, I make feature request for framework.

Comment: @kicaj you can give it a try, but I am 99% sure it will get dismissed as it is hard to add and adds no value to the current ecosystem, and you can already do what I did. I am sure you will get the same answer "use RAW SQL and insert in that way", but you can try adding this as an idea

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can either do this:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

or this:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

or:
Create/update both models in an isolated way.